# doGet() function advice

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, scripting

I am trying to have this script move the active `selection/cursor` to a defined `row/column` that is defined in the `url (...?range=23:23)` as a parameter. So far I haven't been able to figure it out exactly.. I believe I am close but I am not certain where to go from here.

```
    function doGet(e){
        var range = e.parameter.range;
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  sheet.setActiveSelection(range).activate();

}
```

It says **"The script completed but did not return anything."**

Comment: Should work. What's the problem? Did it activate?

Comment: I just get a an error that says it didn't return anything.

Comment: That's not a error. You didn't return anything from the function. `return 'Success'` at the end will return success text. Regardless, Your sheet, which you should've  manually opened in the browser should've activated  range 23:23